# PySpark: NameError: name 'col' is not defined

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find the length of a dataframe column, I am running the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
def check_field_length(dataframe: object, name: str, required_length: int):
    dataframe.where(length(col(name)) >= required_length).show()
```

When I run it it gives error:

```
   dataframe.where(length(col(name)) >= required_length).show()
NameError: name 'col' is not defined
```

*Spark Version*: version 3.0.0

Comment: Can you add the entire stacktrace and also did you tried - `from pyspark.sql.functions import as F` - `dataframe.where(F.length(F.col(name)) >= required_length).show()`

Comment: I tested it, and it works. How do you call the function?

Comment: @Vaebhav it gives syntax error. `from pyspark.sql.functions import as F `

Comment: @Vaebhav `import pyspark.sql.function as F` worked. Though not sure what wrong was I doing?

Comment: @Volatil3 - Even I m curious , your implementation had nothing wrong in it